# Отразить изображение

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять в чём дело, программа зависает. Хотя при ручном нажатии(без цикла) - всё работает.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1() Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
    While (True)
        PictureBox2.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: А как вы вообще до такого додумались? :)

Comment: Только `While (True)`
Давно не видел VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button1_Click_1 срабатывает в потоке UI, соответственно,

> PictureBox2.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX)
>
> Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

делает RotateFlip, а потом усыпляет UI поток на две секунды.
Используйте (Силу) делегат и передавайте его в новый поток, который уже можно усыплять сколько угодно (Но из бесконечного цикла выход предусмотреть было бы неплохо)

Answer (score 0):

Э, а как ты из цикла выходить будешь?? Интерфейс не обновляется. Сделай через `Timer`. Создай объект таймера, установи на 2000 мс,в нем найди Tick, запусти таймер. А чтобы твой плохой пример работал используй `Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: @semenvx27 мне казалось : 1) да это бесконечный цикл 2) но картинка могла бы каждые 2 секунды отражаться (вечно)